# Weak solution of SDE

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Show that the SDE

$dX_t=dB_t-\frac{Bt}{1-t}dt$

has a weak solution on $[0,t]$ for $0\ge t<1$.

I tried it with Girsanov's theorem. But I can't prove that
$E[\exp(\int_0^t\left(\frac{Bs}{1-s}\right)^2ds]<\infty$ which would imply that $Z_t:=\exp(M_t-\frac{1}{2}\langle M\rangle_t)$ is a continuous martingale $\iff E[Z_t]=1 \quad \forall t\ge0.$ So I can't apply Girsanov.

Comment: I guess there is a typo in your question, because that's actually not really an SDE ... there is no $X_t$ on the right-hand side of your equation.

Comment: As soon as you have fixed the typo, you might be interested in the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/306252/

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Hope that it help you :to prove this $$E[\exp(\int_0^t\left(\frac{Bs}{1-s}\right)^2ds]<\infty$$ 
note that
    $0<s<t<1 \\$ so  $ \exists n_0: s^{n_0}<\epsilon$
$$\dfrac{B_s}{1-s}=B_s(1+s+s^2+s^3+...)\\\to \\B_s(1+s+s^2+s^3+...)<B_s .M$$